# Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string while descrying users password

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption

I am trying to decrypt users password while login using below method but while decrypting it shows below error

> Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string.

```
private string Decrypt(string cipherText)
{
    string EncryptionKey = "MAKV2SPBNI99212";
    byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
    using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
    {
        Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
        encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
        encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);
                cs.Close();
            }
            cipherText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray());
        }
    }
    return cipherText;
}
```

Comment: It seems like `cipherText` is containing an invalid Base64 string. Can you post it? Also, if that's your real `EncryptionKey`, then edit your post and hide that.

Comment: @Icemanind Generated encryption key is ydVW2noS7MAGsPNyKjlfb+G8G68Ad3Yd6Z2Cs+HEbZjGjL302dkNLATWip2qpXjs

Comment: `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` is a hashing algorithm (`PBKDF2`), so there is actually nothing really to "decrypt" here... Are you trying to create a login functionality, or what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @bassfader from one domain user is already logged in. I am just fetching username from domain1 and encrypting it. Then passing encrypted string to domain2 using querystring. Now I want to decrypt it to domain2

Comment: It seems like you have some non ascii characters after the 60th character.

Comment: @SUN you're not "encrypting" the username, you're calculating a hash of the username. As I said, the `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` is a hashing algorithm, so there is nothing to "decrypt"... If you really want to encrypt some text that you can decrypt later then you need a real encryption algorithm, for example like the [`RijndaelManaged` algorithm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanaged(v=vs.110).aspx).